# Parameter classes for @ContextConfiguration cannot be recognized

Tags: java, spring, context-configuration

In the following test class

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull(){
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }
}
```

compiler hightlights parameter classes in line

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CDPlayerConfig.class)
```

as an error. Class CDPlayerConfing is easily found.It is marked as Config class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {
}
```

Do I miss some import?

Comment: How `CDPlayerConfig` is added to Spring? config class? xml configuration? can you show part of the code?

Comment: It is marked with @Configuration annotation. I've edited the question.

Comment: Why don't you have import of `CDPlayerConfig` in `CDPlayerTest`?

Comment: I've added the import. It's grayed out, as non-used import. Still the same error during running test. 
Error:(14, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method classes()
  location: @interface org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I have been using old Maven dependency for tests

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've changed version for 5.0.1.RELEASE and it worked.